# Add other files in Python distribution

Tags: python, packaging, python-packaging

I am working on a project which I have to share as a standalone SDK with my team. For some reason files other than *.py are not being added to my distribution file

My project structure is as given below

[image]

My Setup.py is like this

```
import setuptools
from glob import glob
from os.path import basename
from os.path import splitext

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    install_requires = f.read().splitlines()[2:]

with open('requirements-dev.txt') as f:
    tests_require = f.read().splitlines()[2:]

extras = {
    'test': tests_require,
}

setuptools.setup(
    name='eu-taxonomy-sdk',
    version='0.0.2',
    author='Bhushan Fegade',
    author_email='bhushan.fegade@morningtar.com',
    description='a calculation library for eu-taxonomy',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://msstash.morningstar.com/scm/dataapi/eu-taxonomy-sdk.git',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    package_data={'eu-taxonomy-sdk': [ 'config/*', 'category/config/*' ]},
    py_modules=[splitext(basename(path))[0] for path in glob('src/*.py')],
    license='Apache Software License',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
    install_requires=install_requires,
    python_requires='~=3.8',
    tests_require=tests_require,
    extras_require=extras,
    test_suite='tests'
)
```

I am using the following commands to generate a distributable file

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py sdist
```

I have tried making some changes in the `setup.py` file but the distributable file inside the `config` folder is always empty with only the **init**.py file and no other file is present.

I want to know if there is a way to keep those other files(CSV, parq) in the final distributable file.

Comment: Why not using the option :
data_files=[('other files', ['myfile_1.csv', "myfolder/myfile_2.csv"])]
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [a `MANIFEST.in` file](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) that describes the files you need included.

E.g.

```
recursive-include src *.csv *.parq
```